# Help with Matrices operations and groups

Tags: group-theory, matrices, vector-spaces

I have just finished a chapter concerning matrices and I am trying to solve a problem with Matrices and * operations.

Specifically the question is as follows:

> Denote by $A$ the set of $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices , i.e. matrices $M$ such that $M^T = -M$, where $M^T$ denotes the transpose of $M$, and define the operation $*$ on $A$ by $L*M=LM - ML$
>   for $L,M \in A$.
>
> (a) Show that $A$ is closed under this operation, i.e. that if $L,M \in A$ then $L*M \in Α$.
>
> (b) Is $A$ a group with this operation?

Comment: I have reformatted your question to reflect the formatting conventions used on this site. Please review the editing for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

For first part, you can do via @Sigur's hint. For the second part, lets search for a probable identity element, if exists. Assume $M$ is such that element so for arbitrary $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix $L\neq \bar{0}_{3\times 3}$, we should see that $$M*L=L*M=L$$ so we should have $$ML-LM=L\\LM-ML=L$$ This leads us to $L=\bar{0}_{3\times 3}$. A contradiction! Note that $$\bar{0}_{3\times 3}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have to show that $(L*M)^T=-(L*M)$. You need to use the fact that $(LM)^T=M^TL^T$ and $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$.

Comment: I have corrected an obvious misprint.

Comment: hmmm, if you could take it one step further...

Comment: Still do not have it...

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, note that $L * 0 = 0 = M * 0$ for all $L, M \in A$ (where $0$ is the zero $3 \times 3$ matrix), so since $A \ne \{ 0 \}$, the cancellation law does not hold, that is, $0$ does not have an inverse.